# Php Active Record Remove Connection

Tags: php, activerecord

Im using [PHP Active Record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/index/main) - Does anyone know how you **kill a connection**? 
I need to kill it, so I can re-connect and have a fresh connection rather than leave it idle until it expires.

This is how I instantiate it:

```
    ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory(APPLICATION_PATH . 'model');
        $cfg->set_connections(array('development' => DB_TYPE.'://'.DB_USER.':'.DB_PASS.'@'.DB_HOST.'/'.DB_NAME));
    });
```

I have tried this, yet it is not a method:

```
ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::drop_connection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is working so far when I updated to the latest [Github PHP Active Record](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord) which has quite a few different files. I was confused as the ZIP on their site is very out of date versus the GitHub.

The new copy seems to have an [auto-restablish](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/commit/aed05c2ac86457bafb41c386072701e8e9228b9e), I didn't have to do this manually (yet)